# CanoScan Lide 120 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: canon, scanner

Just bought a 'Canoscan Lide 120' scanner that I plan to use on a windows 7 laptop. In Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit it is detected by 'sane-find-scanner' but with 'Simple Scan' I just get: "No scanners detected". Any hope???

Comment: Here's a lead you could check out: http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/canon_lide_120.html

Comment: @Marc: that driver doesn't have Linux support (yet).

Comment: It seems that the SANE driver _might_ be working now. It is in the _Untested_ state ([here](http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-backends-cvs.html#S-GENESYS)). Note that the Lide 220, which has a higher resolution and one more button has the driver in the _Complete_ state.

Comment: @jorcas, do you have any update on this? Is the scanner now working as suggested by Walter Tross?

Comment: more accurate answer in http://askubuntu.com/questions/652769/running-canon-120-lide-scanner-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 3):

Now the canon LiDE 120 runs on Ubuntu 14.04 and even tested in 16.04 as well, for this you have to do the following:

To add the SANE PPA so that you have the latest version of SANE (backport), open your terminal and type

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git
```

then run

```
$ sudo apt update
```

then run

```
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Or if you do not have sane and all its libraries installed then install it by executing the following.

```
$ sudo apt -y install sane libsane libsane-common sane-utils libsane-extras
```

you can also use synaptic package manager to check and make sure that sane is up-to-date with all necessary libraries.

Now your scanner should work with any frontends like simple-scan or gscan2pdf.

or you can compile `sane-backend` from the latest source, that will also do the job, in that case you have to have `libusb-dev build-essential libsane-dev` and for avahi network support `libavahi-client-dev libavahi-glib-dev` installed on your system. To do the compiling, you can follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompileSaneFromSource
and it will help you some more https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane

Comment: Unfortunately, this installs, but doesn't fix the issue with the scanner. Apparently detecting the `LiDE120` isn't hard, but it uses a newer controller chip which isn't yet fully supported by XSANE. Using the latest source, I get nothing but full black pages, and some bad noise from the motor (XSane killed my previous `LiDE` scanner too, I suspect). You can remove the above installed software via: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`, and 
`sudo ppa-purge ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git`. Thanks for the advice anyways.

Comment: @DevNull, what Ubuntu release you are using? That PPA supports up to Xenial, for further query, you need to contact the SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy - A unified project to add support for scanners to all Linux varients) developer Rolf Bensch directly. Have you tried "Simple Scan" or gscan2pdf tool to scan it?  What is the result of `sudo dpkg -l libsane` and `sudo scanimage -V` after activating that PPA or after compiling the backend from the latest source?

Comment: I tried with Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64 (LTS), on kernel `4.4.0-45-generic`. Everything is up-to-date with `apt`. I tried with the commands noted above after installing the custom PPA (even rebooted), and no joy.

Comment: @DevNull I am using the device Canon LiDE 120 right now with 16.04.1 with "Simple Scan" tool as front-end with the help of that PPA and here are some success reports and special cases you'll find https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/262320 :)

Comment: Thank you for that information. I will re-test this tomorrow. :)