# Running Canon 120 LiDE scanner on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, canon, scanner

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 virtually. I know that the Canon 120 LiDE cannot run on Ubuntu, but would I be able to run it through Windows 7 virtually?

Answer (score 6):

Now the canon LiDE 120 runs on Ubuntu 14.04 and tested in 16.04 as well, for this you have to do the following:

To add the SANE PPA so that you have the latest version of SANE (proposed)
or for (backport), check out the following links
https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-release and

https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git accordingly.

And now open your terminal and type

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-release
```

then run

```
$ sudo apt update
```

then (assuming the user has the sane and all sane libraries installed) do a full-upgrade by

```
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

If you do not have sane and all its libraries installed then install it by executing the following.

```
$ sudo apt -y install sane libsane libsane-common sane-utils libsane-extras
```

Now your scanner should work with any frontends like simple-scan or gscan2pdf.

or you can compile `sane-backend` from the latest source, for that you can follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompileSaneFromSource.
and it will help your system recognizing your device https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane, and the current sourcecode is hosted here https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends

Comment: I can confirm that this worked. Every other approaches failed.

Comment: Did this version of SANE reach the official repositories? It would be useful to update http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON which says LiDE 120 is unsupported. It is listed as supported in the git version though: http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-mfgs-cvs.html

Answer (score 1):

You try to edit a file /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
```

In te open file add the following 2 lines:

```
# Canon CanoScan Lide 120
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="190e", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Close the terminal,

Reboot.

And run:

```
sudo sane-find-scanner -v -v
```

Answer (score -1):

# Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

# Not checking for parallel port scanners.

# Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
done
zorin@zorin-E2050-2391:~$ -L
-L: Befehl nicht gefunden.
zorin@zorin-E2050-2391:~$ scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).