# Problem with scanner Canoscan LiDE 120, image is black, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: scanner

The scanner is working correctly under windows and is detected correctly under ubuntu 16.04.

I was expecting this link
[CanoScan LiDE 120 on Ubuntu 16.04: Scan completely black](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814137/canoscan-lide-120-on-ubuntu-16-04-scan-completely-black)
to solve the problem as my symptoms seem to be exactly the same as given there but it hasn't worked.

For the first command I got this, pressing ENTER to continue where told, I'm not sure what the keyring etc means, did it work?

```
alex@alex-16:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git
 Ubuntu SANE packages from SANE daily git snapshots (http://www.sane-project.org/snapshots/).

Unchanged SANE daily git snapshots are ignored!

Please send scanner related questions to the SANE mailing list <email address hidden>.

If you need the last released scanner driver, you can use my other PPA: https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-release.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpxabubqvw/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpxabubqvw/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key B7CC8701 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpxabubqvw/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key B7CC8701: public key "Launchpad PPA for Rolf Bensch" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
alex@alex-16:~$
```

After this I entered "sudo apt-get update" as instructed and this seems ok. Because it contains more than 8 links I was told I couldn't post all of it.

```
alex@alex-16:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease                                                                                        
......
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rolfbensch/sane-git/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                
Hit:11 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                         
Hit:13 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Fetched 306 kB in 0s (347 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
alex@alex-16:~$
```

After this my symptoms were not changed and I'm not sure what to try next.

Well, anyway, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

That keyring stuff is expected when you add the ppa.

When you did `sudo apt-get update`, the list of program sources is refreshed, but no actual updates are done.

To actually incorporate the updates from the ppa, you must do `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Once you do that, as of today, if you do an `apt-cache policy libsane` and see this in the first line of the results

`Installed: 1.0.27+git20171029-xenial0`

then you will have indeed installed the latest software from that ppa.

I can't tell if this will actually help your problem, but there is a good chance it will.  It helped with our Canon scanner problems.

Note: It is possible that your question should be closed as a duplicate of the one you mention.  I'm choosing to interpret it instead as a question about you having difficulty incorporating the solution found in that question's answer.