# Thick black vertical line with Canon LiDE 100 scanner in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, canon, scanner

As mentioned in the title, there is thick black vertical line in the middle of every document that I scan with Canon LiDE 100 scanner in Ubuntu 17.10.
It was working perfectly fine with Ubuntu 17.04. It works completely fine with Windows 10.
Following is the screenshot of an empty scan.
[image]
I tried the solution given [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/755505), but it didn't help, resulting in the same output.
Can anyone suggest any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can confirm this issue with all my Ubuntu 17.10 devices. I can also confirm that all my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS devices don't have this issue with the CanoScan LiDE 100. Update: This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1729077 Please click the "I am affected by this bug" on the upper left corner (green text) and comment if you have any additional details.

Comment: This has been reported as a bug that aaffects Ubuntu 17.10: [wrong color of horizontally centered area of scan with CanoScan Lide 200](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1729077)